# The support of the unbounded operator

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

If $x\in B(H)$ and $x=x^*$, then the support $s(x)$ of $x$ can be defined as following:

$s(x)$ is the smallest projection $e\in B(H)$ such that $ex=x=xe$.

If $x$ is an unbounded self-adjoint operator, how to define the support projection of $x$?

More precisely, if $x$ is a self-adjoint unbounded operator which is affiliated with a von Neumann algebra $M$. If we take the above definition, we cannot assure that $s(x)x$ make sense.

Comment: This is not an answer, because I don't know that this is an accepted definition.  But there's nothing logically wrong with asking for the smallest projection $ e $ such that $ e x = x = x e $; it's just that part of requiring $ e x = x = x e $ is requiring that $ e x $ and $ x e $ exist.